# Выполнить функцию после нажатия на кнопку

Tags: изображения, javascript, функции

**Ситуация:**

После нажатия на кнопку происходит переход на страницу del.php

```
<?php echo "<button onclick=\"location.href='del.php'\">Удалить файлы</button>" ?>
```

**Вопрос:**

Как выполнить функцию PHP без перехода на страницу del.php

***P.S***

*Функция PHP должна выполняться только после нажатия на кнопку!*

**Функция:**

```
if (file_exists('./img'))
foreach (glob('./img/*') as $file)
unlink($file);

$var = 'Файлы каталога успешно удалены';
print '<script>alert("'.$var.'");</script>'
```

Comment: К нижеприведенным ответом хочу добавить,что не стоит производить никаких действий через GET запросы. Велика вероятность что вам дадут посмотреть картинку с адресом del.php, ну и в идеале используйте csrf token'ы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А я предлагаю не подключать лишние библиотеки, а использовать фрейм.

```
<a href="delp.php" target="transportFrame">Удалить файлы</a>
<iframe name="transportFrame" width="1" height="1" border="0">Все плохо!</iframe>
```

или так:

```
<button onclick="transportFrame.location.href='del.php'">Удалить файлы</button>
<iframe name="transportFrame" width="1" height="1" border="0">Все плохо!</iframe>
```

А что выбрать, ajax или фрейм - решать Вам.

Comment: ага, можно еще картинку сгенерить с `src=del.php?file=file&rand=2823`

Comment: fremail

СПС

Но страница на которой кнопка, после удаления файлов не перезагружается. Остаётся список файлов.

Как перезагрузить страницу после нажатия на OK в окне alert?

Вот страница работы PHP и JS http://www.pixelcom.crimea.ua/vzaimodejstvie-php-i-javascript.html

Comment: Самый простой вариант - дописать скрипт на странице del.php:

    print '<script>alert("'.$var.'");self.location.reload();</script>';

Вот только мучает меня 1 вопрос: Зачем в фоновом режиме грузить страницу, потом выдавать alert, а потом обновлять страницу?
Можно было обойтись даже без фреймов - кнопка остается, как Вы и предлагали, происходит переход на страницу del.php, а потом выскакивает alert и скрипт перенаправляет на исходную страницу. Работает во всех браузерах. Лишь бы элементарные скрипты работали.

Comment: Вы правы не обязательно в фоновом режиме грузить страницу. Я пробовал применить history.go(-1) но страница с кнопкой не перезагружается. Было бы неплохо если бы скрипт перенаправлял на исходную страницу. 

Такой скрипт страницу self.location.reload(); не перенаправляет на исходную страницу с кнопкой он просто не знает её. Если оставить фрейм окно alert спрашивает лишний вопрос о повторении, что не хорошо.

Как перезагрузить страницу с кнопкой "Удалить файлы" после нажатия на OK в окне alert?

Comment: Ну history.go(-1); и должен открывать предыдущую страницу...
Есть еще 1 вариант: на кнопку вешаем такой скрипт:

    window.location.href='del.php?'+window.location.toString();

А на странице del.php:

    alert('Удалили файл...');
    window.location.assign(window.location.search.substr(1));

Я не проверял, но работать должно.

Comment: Работает хорошо!

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [ajax](http://javascript.ru/ajax/intro). Можно подключить jquery (это такая javascript-библиотека) и использовать ее функцию [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). В вашем случае, судя по всему, происходит удаление чего-то с сервера. Вообще принято, для таких целей, использовать http-метод delete (вы используете get). Чтобы понять, что я хочу этим сказать почитайте про [rest](http://habrahabr.ru/post/38730/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button').click(function() {

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'del.php',
        data: {
            del: 'Y',
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){
          alert('Ваши файлы удалены');
        }
    });

});
```